# object returned for uint256 return value

Tags: uint256, type-casting, returndata, return

I implemented a method to retrieve a price for a currency via some chainlink price feed. This price is casted to an uint256. But if I call this method via etherscan it does not show a number, but just "object Object". Whats the reason for this and how can I get a number to show up here?

```
function getLatestPrice(address currencyAddress) public view returns (uint256) {
    (, int price, , , ) = priceFeeds[currencyAddress].latestRoundData();

    return uint256(price * 1e10); // Price comes with 8 digits but we need 18
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I created a contract with the following code and deployed it to the goerli testnet [at this address](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x7ced02a72d311d7734def293d520752ba6ccfc02) `0x7cEd02A72d311d7734dEF293D520752BA6CcFc02`.

##### Contract example:

```js
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";

contract ReturnPriceContract {

    mapping (address => AggregatorV3Interface) public priceFeeds;
    constructor() {
        // LINK/USD price feed on goerli
        priceFeeds[0x45442CB17bD3E3C0AeaE92BF425473E582d5e740] = AggregatorV3Interface(0x48731cF7e84dc94C5f84577882c14Be11a5B7456);
    }

    function getLatestPrice(address currencyAddress) public view returns (uint256) {
    AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = priceFeeds[currencyAddress];
    require(address(priceFeed) != address(0), "Price feed not found");

    (, int price, , , ) = priceFeed.latestRoundData();
    require(price > 0, "Invalid price");

    uint256 scaledPrice = uint256(price) * 1e10;
    return scaledPrice;
}
}
```

##### ethers.js example:

Then I created a quick Node.js script with ethers to fetch the price from `getLatestPrice` for the [LINK](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x45442cb17bd3e3c0aeae92bf425473e582d5e740) token on goerli, to show the returned value as a string:

```js
const ethers = require("ethers");

const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider(
  "https://goerli.infura.io/v3/<api-key>"
);

const abi = [
  "function getLatestPrice(address currencyAddress) public view returns (uint256)",
];

// contract address for ReturnPriceContract deployed on goerli
const contractAddress = "0x7cEd02A72d311d7734dEF293D520752BA6CcFc02";
const contract = new ethers.Contract(contractAddress, abi, provider);

async function main() {
  const price = await contract.getLatestPrice(
    "0x45442CB17bD3E3C0AeaE92BF425473E582d5e740"
  );
  // this returns at the time of writing "8216626120000000000"
  console.log(price.toString());
}

main();
```

##### Etherscan Goerli example:

Additionally, I verified the contract `0x7cEd02A72d311d7734dEF293D520752BA6CcFc02` on the goerli testnet - if I read the `getLatestPrice` for `0x45442CB17bD3E3C0AeaE92BF425473E582d5e740` on [the goerli etherscan contract page](https://goerli.etherscan.io/address/0x7ced02a72d311d7734def293d520752ba6ccfc02#code), you will see the LINK price returned as `uint` on etherscan.

[image: etherscan return uint example]

Hope this helps!

Comment: I forgot to mention: The code is solidity code. There is no toNumber() function.

Comment: please have a look, I have put together an example for you.